# how can i get remove button on facebook icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: remove button on facebook icon]

**UPDATED**

how can i get remove button on facebook icon like above picture ??
i want put remove button on top right corner to the facebook icon ....
[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/x9cqZVbt3yQQ6noSUKWN?p=preview)

```css
.fa-remove{
    float:right;
    top:-30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #605F61;
    font-size: 31px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.12.0/bootstrap-social.css">


  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="form-group social col-xs-2">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-social-icon btn-facebook center-block">
                        <span class="fa fa-facebook"><span class="fa-remove"></span>
                    </a>
                    <p class="social-icon-name">Facebook</p>
                </div>
                

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be great if you can provide us your CSS too.

Comment: remove icon is already there but you need to increse width of btn-facebook now getting hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about position absolute.

You have so many error in your code. But this is not, what yo need.

You need this:

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-social-icon btn-facebook center-block">
   <span class="facebook">
  </a>
  <span class="fa-remove"></span>

 .fa-remove{ 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  right:15px; 
  z-index:9999; 
  float:right; 
  top:-30px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  color: #fff; 
  border: 1px solid #AEAEAE; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
  background: #605F61; 
  font-size: 31px; 
  }
```

Comment: but i need to get remove icon at the corner of facebook icon and it must be come closeup to us..

Comment: Get your <span class="fa-remove"></span> from <a element and rewrite your css


`.fa-remove{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:15px;
    z-index:9999;
    float:right;
    top:-30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #605F61;
    font-size: 31px;
}`

Comment: remove icon have to come out side to the facebook icon ,, how to change ? in ur code remove icon coming in facebook icon only ... can u pls check my given picture hint  .. ?

Comment: Did you solved? I change your code on plunker and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code but you can try this.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-social-icon btn-facebook center-block">
    <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></span>
</a>
```

And in your css

```
.fa.fa-remove {
    color: #f00;
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
```

Change the values of top and left accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use below code it may help you

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.12.0/bootstrap-social.css">
<div class="form-group social col-xs-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-social-icon btn-facebook center-block">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> </i>
                    </a>
                    <p class="social-icon-name">Facebook</p>
                </div>
```